# Check if service is available

Tags: android, service, bindservice

I need to know if a specific service is available (running or can be created) before calling `Context.bindService`.

Is there a way to check that ?

Answer (score 0):

please see the comments

```
 ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)    {
    // capture the service object , check for alive or not
         service.isBinderAlive(); 

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        }
    };
```